# how to get parameters from a combo in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to the angular frontend and I need help in this case, 
I have a modal with combo and one input text, and I need to put 
these parameters in my controller, according to the code below:

My combo in archive html

```
  <select ng-model="controller.labelType" 
    style="width: 500px"
    name="labelType"
    id="labelType"
    class="form-control"
    ng-options="labelType as labelType.label for labelType in labelType track by labelType.id"
    placeholder="{{'application.labelSelect.labelType' | translate}}">
    <option value="" >{{'application.labelSelect.labelType' | translate}}</option>
  </select>
```

Combo in my controller

```
$scope.labelType = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'Option1',
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'Option2',
    }];
```

my input field1 html

```
<input ng-model="controller.field1"
       style="width: 500px"
       id="field1" 
       name="field1" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control fontSizeWizard" 
       maxlength="20
/>
```

When press the button, send the parameters to the controller, for example:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        ngclick="controller.passParametersToController(labelType,fieldtext)" 
        data-dismiss="modal">
        {{'buttons.save'| translate}}
</button
```

Then I need to receive on my controller, for example

```
this.receiveParameters = function (labelType,fieldtext) {
 code...
});
```

Not sure how to correctly pass and get these parameters.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

```
<select ng-model="selectValue"
...
</select>

<input ng-model="inputValue"
...
```

From controller access to this parameters:

```
console.log($scope.selectValue);
consile.log($scope.inputValue);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Perfect Petrenko. Thank very much.